# Apollo: passing root to resolver with info.mergeInfo.delegateToSchema

Tags: graphql, apollo, graphql-tools

I have a stitched graphql schema. Some type fields are resolved with `info.mergeInfo.delegateToSchema`

Here's an example (which is from the [apollo docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/schema-stitching.html#adding-resolvers)):

```
const mergedSchema = mergeSchemas({
  schemas: [
    transformedChirpSchema,
    authorSchema,
    linkTypeDefs,
  ],
  resolvers: {
    User: {
      chirps: {
        fragment: `... on User { id }`,
        resolve(user, args, context, info) {
          return info.mergeInfo.delegateToSchema({
            schema: chirpSchema,
            operation: 'query',
            fieldName: 'chirpsByAuthorId',
            args: {
              authorId: user.id,
            },
            context,
            info,
          });
        },
      },
    },
});
```

Is it possible to access `root` in `chirps` resolver? So that in the `root` there were all the parent fields? Another way is, of course, to use `context` for this purpose, but using root, I guess, would be better from a code perspective as I'm already using `root` value in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

Under the hood `info.mergeInfo.delegateToSchema` can call remote GraphQL application (more [details](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/remote-schemas.html)).

So by design remote resolver don't have access to local root/context/info/arg, you need send all required data in arguments for remote field. For example:

```
const mergedSchema = mergeSchemas({
  schemas: [
    transformedChirpSchema,
    authorSchema,
    linkTypeDefs,
  ],
  resolvers: {
    User: {
      chirps: {
        fragment: `... on User { id }`,
        resolve(user, args, context, info) {
          return info.mergeInfo.delegateToSchema({
            schema: chirpSchema,
            operation: 'query',
            fieldName: 'chirpsByAuthorId',
            args: {
              // author is InputType at remove schema with similar user structure
              author: user,
            },
            context,
            info,
          });
        },
      },
    },
});
```

I don't know your case, but don't forgot about [schema-transforms](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/schema-transforms.html) during working with remove schemas.